# State Space with Space Lags in R (dlm, MARSS or anything else)

Tags: r, kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

** Edited to reflect on some first comments **

I am trying to estimate a state space model which does a kind of disaggregation. In particular, I am interested in estimating high-frequency unobserved states from low frequency observations. For example, disaggregate annual observable to quarterly equivalents, or quarterly to monthly (e.g., quarterly GDP to monthly disaggregated estimates, etc.).

**Question 1:** Taking the annual to quarterly example, to formulate the above in state space, I am thinking to have a state which mainly is like an AR(3) of the state (but also including the $t$ of the state - not just the lags).

In particular, $y_{t} = x_{t} + x_{t-1} + x_{t-2} + x_{t-3}$, this is the sum restriction, i.e. $y_{1998} = x_{1998q4} + x_{1998q3} + x_{1998q2} + x_{1998q1}$.

Would this be an appropriate formulation:

$$y_{t}=F\theta _{t}$$
$$\theta _{t}=G\theta _{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$$

where $\theta _{t}=\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_{t} \\ 
x_{t-1} \\ 
x_{t-2} \\ 
x_{t-3}%
\end{array}%
\right] $

$F=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right] $

$G=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho _{0} & \rho _{1} & \rho _{2} & \rho _{3} \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right] $

**Question 2:** if the above seems reasonable, is there any easy way to implement it with existing packages in R? The main difficulty here is to have a main state, i.e. $x_{t}$, and its lags together as a state...

P.S.: This question -unfortunately- is in the boundaries between CV and stackexchange as it is neither code-oriented (per se), nor pure theory.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: @Taylor thanks for both your comments. I have now edited the whole message with more info (re your first comment). Re your second comment, please see my PS and thanks for the reminder...